# Implementing add to cart in React + Redux results in error, cannot fetch added products

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So, I'm trying to add a product to cart, which is the object, specified by quantity which is passed in url parameters. It will look like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/cart/622d6150a1d5f82535d4b66c?qty=3
```

I managed to split the quantity (qty) parameter by using useLocation, but I somehow cannot console log the cartItems which contain the products that have been added to the cart.

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {Link, useLocation, useNavigate, useParams, useSearchParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import {addToCart} from '../actions/cartActions'

export const CartScreen = () => {
  const productId = useParams()
  const history = useNavigate()
  const useQty = useLocation()

  const qty = useQty.search ? Number(useQty.search.split('=')[1]) : 1

  console.log(qty)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
  const {cartItems} = cart

  console.log(cartItems)

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(productId){
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty))
    }
  },[dispatch, productId, qty])



  return (
    <div>CartScreen</div>
  )
}

export default CartScreen
```

the console shows something like this, it shows 3 from the url parameter but shows an empty array where it should've been show the array of the products that I've been added to the cart. Also, What is the `GET http://localhost:3000/api/products/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)` mean? FYI, the products was fetched from mongodb which is in localhost:5000/api/products but get proxy through localhost:3000

[image: console]

If this is any help, as I'm also using Redux, here is my addToCart actions, the redux store file, cart reducers as well.

```
import axios from "axios";
import { CART_ADD_ITEM } from "../constants/cartConstants";


export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {data} = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)

    dispatch({
        type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
        payload: {
            product: data._id,
            name: data.name,
            image: data.image,
            price: data.price,
            countInStock: data.countInStock,
            qty
        }
    })

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}
```

```
import {createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import {composeWithDevTools} from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { productListReducer, productDetailsReducer } from './reducers/productReducers'
import { cartReducer } from './reducers/cartReducers'

const reducer = combineReducers({
    productList: productListReducer,
    productDetails: productDetailsReducer,
    cart: cartReducer,
})

const cartItemsFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('cartItems') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cartItems')) : []

const initialState = {
    cart: {cartItems: cartItemsFromLocalStorage},
}

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(reducer, 
    initialState, 
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))

export default store
```

```
import {CART_ADD_ITEM} from "../constants/cartConstants"

export const cartReducer = (state = {cartItems: []}, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item = action.payload

            const existItem = state.cartItems.find(x => x.product === item.product)

            if(existItem){
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map(x => x.product === existItem.product ? item : x),
                }
            } else {
                return{
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item]
                }

            }
        default:
        return state

    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by using restructuring the variables in CartScreen.js like this:

```
const {productId} = useParams()
const useQty = useLocation()

const qty = useQty.search ? Number(useQty.search.split('=')[1]) : 1
```

To this:

```
const { id } = useParams();
const { search } = useLocation();
  
const productId = id;
const qty = search ? Number(search.split("=")[1]) : 1;
```

Now it shows the product details in the array, I honestly don't know what is happening here.
[image: console]

Answer (score 0):

You just have one tiny mistake in your `CartScreen` component. You are directly trying to extract the `productId` using `useParams` and you can't do that. Because `useParams` returns an `object`.

So if you want to extract any `dynamic value` using `useParams`. You have to `destructure` it like below:

```
const { productId } = useParams()
```

Comment: the ```GET http://localhost:3000/api/products/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)``` error is now gone, but I still get an empty array [] when adding product to the cart, I have no idea why